# What to do when a PhD supervisor is not collaborating on publications after the PhD from it?

Tags: phd, publications, thesis, intellectual-property, supervision

If someone's (SO) PhD supervisor is not collaborating on publications from SO's PhD. The problem arose as SO raised his mistrust (for the supervisor) on other academic issues. The supervisor treats student's work as his, and SO does not agree with that.

SO has one paper just rejected from a journal but could be submitted in another journal. This is from SO's PhD, so he would like to publish it and more from the PhD. SO is not sure how to go ahead with this, (with the supervisor or without). The paper is intellectually SO's but the supervisor helped in improving the writing (of the rejected paper). As the supervisor is refusing to collaborate, how can SO publish that? Can SO do that without supervisor name? What could be the consequences?

Answer (score 6):

If the advisor made a substantial intellectual contribution (or, in fields where it's relevant, procured the grant supporting the work), there's not much the author can do to publish the paper without the advisor's permission. The advisor would have claim to authorship rights if:

- the paper grew out of work proposed by the advisor, or was supported by funds accrued by the advisor;
- the student discussed the work with the advisor and gained useful feedback or guidance about the direction or results of the project;
- the advisor contributed to the writing of the paper.

The last point is definitely true; it's not clear if the first two points hold, but they very well could, given the situation described.

Basically, if the advisor has authorship rights, the student is more or less screwed if they try to publish. If they publish the paper, with an author who has not given permission for submission or without an author who has authorship rights, then that is sufficient grounds for **retraction** of a paper.

Comment: _Unless the author received no support from the advisor_ — I think you misspelled "Unless the advisor made no significant intellectual contribution to the work".  I do _not_ automatically have authorship rights to my PhD students' work, even if I paid them to work on a problem I proposed. (This is field-specific.)

Comment: @JeffE: It is in part field-specific. In engineering, it's essentially unheard of to publish a paper without your advisor's name appearing on it. But I've made it clearer—I meant support in all its forms, intellectual and financial.

Comment: Um... According to my university, I'm an engineer. And the revision doesn't really help, since financial support does _not_ necessarily buy coauthorship.  What you presumably mean is "If someone has contributed enough to be a coauthor, you absolutely cannot publish without their permission, even (especially?) if that someone is your former advisor."

Answer (score 4):

I will try to add my perspective, since I have been in sort-of an opposite situation. In many places and fields, **improving the writing is considered as a part of the job of your supervisor, and if the result is yours, it is yours.** I mean, your supervisor is there to learn you how to write papers, and only if you do the research together, it is necessary to include his name on the paper. (Disclaimer: this is only one point of view, and only on the ethics, not on the legal view).

**Example:** I have a paper where I'm the only author. We were writing the paper down together with my supervisor, and it was certainly her who had more ideas on how to write things down (especially the introduction and the conclusions), which articles should be cited etc. Still, all the ideas were mine, all the proofs were mine (it's theoretical CS), so she said that I should be the only author.

**What should you do?** No, you should not, in my opinion, submit the results without your supervisor's consent. IMHO you can:

- Try to approach him again.
- Ask someone else at the same department for help. Just be careful who you choose, either it should be someone you know well and who knows you well, or someone who is dedicated for these cases: someone who should be approached in case of conflicts. The solution is not clear at all, and having insight from someone close in topic, scientific habits etc. could be helpful.
- Publish your thesis electronically on some public repository; this is at least a step how to make your result visible to the community, and you certainly doesn't need your supervisor's permission to do that. For instance [arXiv](http://arxiv.org) accepts theses.

Comment: _I have a paper where I'm the only author. However, my supervisor likely wrote more of the text than I did, especially the introduction, she chose the references etc_ — Please tell me this is hypothetical.  Because if it's not, your advisor has seriously failed you. **Never let your advisor do work for you,** (Yes, I'm also in TCS.)

Comment: @JeffE It is true. I was probably exaggerating. I basically mean that we were sitting next to each other and she was showing me the way how to do it. And needed to say, it was during my masters, and it was the very first publication I've had. I'll try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on the legalities/ethics of academic publishing. However, here are my 2 cents.

I think if you want to publish papers based on your PhD you should do so.
As far as I know, there is nothing that requires you to get your supervisor's permission to publish your own PhD work. You are also not required to work with him if you don't want to. I think there may be some pressure to put his name on the paper, even if he has not done anything.

So, if I want to go ahead, I would do so. If/when the paper (or papers) get to the point of submission, it might be a good idea to ask him if he wants his name included on the paper.

It sounds from what you say that you already don't have good relations with your supervisor, so you don't have a lot to lose.

Comment: This is *completely* wrong: the author has a **lot** to lose. If someone else has authorship rights on a publication (as is likely the case here) and you do not list them as an author, **the excluded author can get the paper retracted.**

Comment: @aeismail: According to the question: "The paper is intellectually SO's but the supervisor helped in improving the writing (of the rejected paper)." The supervisor is now refusing to collaborate. I think the author is well within his rights to proceed. I said "it might be a good idea to ask him if he wants his name included on the paper". I could strengthen this to "it is advisable to ask him...", but the point remains that the author does not require his supervisor's permission to publish his own work. He is not the supervisor's slave or servant.

Comment: The excluded author can't get the paper retracted if the author can prove (a) the intellectual content of the paper is mostly his (b) that the supervisor was unwilling to collaborate (c) that the supervisor was asked whether he wants his name on the paper and said no. Documentation in this cases is obviously a very good idea. He could (and likely would) make himself unpleasant to the author, but that is another issue.

Comment: If an author renounces a claim to authorship, that's one thing. But so long as she retains those rights, she has the right to block submission if she feels that the manuscript is not ready. Refusal to collaborate does not excuse the corresponding author from securing permission. And "mostly his" is not sufficient: it must be _entirely_ the student's work.

Comment: @aeismail: I'm not aware of any such rules. Do you have any citations/documentation for this? One question to ask here is how would one determine the validity of a claim on authorship? In practice I suppose this is something the journal would determine.

Comment: Just take a look at [_Retraction Watch_](http://www.retractionwatch.com) and the articles related to [authorship issues](http://retractionwatch.com/category/by-reason-for-retraction/authorship-issues/), which are about 5 to 6 percent of the total set of articles they've covered.

Answer (score 1):

The question will benefit from some more clarification. Basically, I feel that just because he has a reputation to claim others' work does not grant you the right to bend the logical decision of assigning authorship.

"Improving the writing" can generally be considered as significant input and thus should lead to an authorship. Whether it may be downgraded to being acknowledged depends on the degree and magnitude of improvement. Changing a couple words here and there probably should go to acknowledgement; anything on par or beyond line editing should conservatively go to authorship, unless it's done by a paid editor/copywriter.

Another information we need to know is what is the supervisor's status in the rejected paper. If he was listed as a co-author, then in subsequent revisions he should be retained as a co-author even he can no longer contribute. An exception is that he explicitly refuses to be listed as a co-author in the next round and on.

Lastly, we'd need to know how did this adviser "refuse to collaborate." Did he refuse to do anything because he believes the first version is good enough? Is he too busy? Or did he say you should drop this article? The stated action is up for too many different interpretations.

Without too many details, I'd say keep him, resubmit and then move on without this person. And should you so loath the idea that he may claim your work, then cut the connection, forget about this paper, and publish independently from him on something new.

Comment: This raises a question of what to do if a collaborator has made significant contributions but refuses to be listed as a coauthor.  Perhaps that is a question in itself.

Answer (score 1):

From an objective point of view, this is a matter of publication ethics. You appear to clearly be the first author, meaning you have provided most of the input from original idea through intellectual work including drawing conclusions.

It is not clear to me if you are past your PhD or in the middle of the PhD. Again, objectively, this would not make any difference but in practise, it involves more. If you are past your PhD, your advisor is not much more than any colleague and you as first author should be able to decide what to do with your work, still considering any co-workers who has made sufficient input to warrant co-authorship. If, on the other hand is still in your PhD you need to think about what you need to do to finish your degree. There must be people around with who you can discuss your situation and the way forward. Providing clear advise on this is quite individual and involves much more than can be deduced from your question.

In both cases, you should make an attempt to properly assess the contributions from all involved in the work. This will provide you with something tangible to use when discussing or defending your rights. Note that you need to include all parts of the process from original idea to the finished product. Many forget the initial question which is where an advisor usually provides much insight. At the same time, providing non-scientific input on writing, is not worth as much as many would think. After all, you could probably buy such a service and no-one would dream of co-authorship. It is as you have indicated the scientific intellectual work that counts.

A difficulty arises when someone, in this case the advisor, refuses to publish  the material. Of course if the reason is that the material is not good enough that is one thing, if it is a personal conflict it is another. The rejected paper is a non-product as I see it. To resubmit, you need to make revisions and then resubmit. You need to send the manuscript to your co-authors (advisor) and state that you are planning to submit to another journal and that you would wish to retain him (and the others) as co-author(s), and invite comments and input.

I recommend you to look at the following links [ICMJE](http://www.icmje.org/ethical_1author.html), [APA](https://www.google.se/search?q=authorship+conflicts+apa&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=tkTuUvqLOqeU4ATz1IGwCA#q=authorship+apa&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial), [Am. Psych.](http://www.apastyle.org/manual/related/fine-1993.pdf), [PARE](http://www.apastyle.org/manual/related/fine-1993.pdf) and [Union University](http://www.uu.edu/programs/nursing/documents/AuthorshipGuidelines.pdf), [AuthorOrder.com](http://www.authorder.com/) to provide a few. the point is: build your own view and knowledge about authorship/contributorship to strengthen your position.

Comment: *All* authors of a paper need to agree to submission of a paper. Failure to secure everyone's agreement for submission of a paper is usually sufficient grounds for retraction.

Comment: Yes, but the question I am getting at is who should be on it.

Comment: You also said: "you as first author should be able to decide what to do with your work." This is not true.

Comment: Do you see anyone else deciding what to do with the PhD material than the PhD student? I do not intend to start a discussion but will think about rephrasing the points you in my opinion have have extrapolated a little too far.

Comment: The co-authors of a paper have to decide that jointly—including the advisor. All of their names appear on the paper, so they all have a right to decide what should happen with the paper.

Comment: Thanks for the critical comments. I have revised the answer but it seems we are approaching the post from opposite directions, advisor's rights vs. student's rights and only the OP will be able to assess the real case.